# KafkaStreams KTable compaction

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, rocksdb

In my application almost every incoming records value is nulled out(tomb-stoned) within a few seconds, however I don't see compaction happening as RocksDB size is not reducing and it still has millions of entries

- When I iterate over the stateStore using keyValue iterator I see that 99% of the values are null (tomb-stones)
- There are around 500 million entries in each stateStore due to which iteration takes close to an hour
- I see that these records do not get eliminated even after few days (waited until 2days). No new input records are sent during testing, so its just old ones hanging around
- I would like the null records to be actively purged to ensure stateStore has mostly active records

I have used **RocksDBConfigSetter** and set **compactionStyle** as **level**:

```
options.setCompactionStyle(CompactionStyle.LEVEL);
```

Please let me know if there is anything else that can be done to trigger frequent compaction

Expected result: 
Null records should be purged quickly at-least in a few hours time

Comment: Any chance you have some iterators that aren't being closed?

Comment: sorry for the delayed reply. We use kstreams DSL, so most iterators are internal. Apart from this we use one read-only iterator on the state store within the try(with resources) block, so would get automatically closed.